# If my LG phone got stuck (as in, did not react to hard reset) in download mode and I had to pull the battery, should I skip attempting to stock flash?

Tags: rom-flashing, lg, stock-rom, setup-wizard

I factory reset my LG k7 phone to help with battery and storage issues, but upon reboot, I found that it was glitching up at the setup screen and says the 'Setup Wizard isn't responding. Would you like to close or wait?" on a black screen.

Due to this, I had planned to go ahead and stock flash it, as I was recommended to do. Before proceeding with this, I decided to test out putting my phone in the required download mode.
But when I tried disconnect it, which, for my phone model, means giving it a forced reset, it didn't respond no matter how long i held the buttons, which left me to assume it was frozen.
I then pulled the battery.

So my question is: should I take this reaction to being put in download mode as a bad sign and skip the stock flash? If the phone were to freeze up like this during the flashing, it would cause an interruption and a likely bricking. What should I do?